# My transitions are working differently for the last label (I want them all to work like the last label)

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

[image]I have added an image of what it currently looks like. I would like them to slide from the box on the right to the left. But the first three have different transition compared to last. Here is what I have done doing so far. Is something wrong with my transition? I have included the CSS code, HTML and image of the outcome.

```
#slider label{
position: relative;
transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide1{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
top: -30%;
left: 20vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide2{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
top: -45vh;
left: 60vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide4, 
#s3:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3{
display: none;
}  

#s2:checked ~ #slide2{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
top: -30%;
left: 20vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

#s2:checked ~ #slide3{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
top: -45vh;
left: 60vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

/*  Slide 3*/

#s3:checked ~ #slide3{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
top: -30%;
left: 20vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

#s3:checked ~ #slide4{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
top: -45vh;
left: 60vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

#s4:checked ~ #slide4{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
top: -116%;
left: 20vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

#s4:checked ~ #slide1{
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
top: -29%;
left: 60vh;
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
}

<section id="slider">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">

        <label for="s1" id="slide1">London</label>
        <label for="s2" id="slide2">Manchester</label>
        <label for="s3" id="slide3">Edinburgh</label>
        <label for="s4" id="slide4">Leeds</label>
    </section>


[Outcome][1]
```

Comment: Could you check your question - I can't see an image.

Comment: @AHaworth I have just updated it, sorry

Comment: Thanks, it looks as though what you want is as if there were a 'pile' of cards on the right and then just one moves to the left depending on which radio button is clicked and the 'next' card shows on top of the pile. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet thinks of the initial position being a pile of cards on the right which move out as the relevant radio button is clicked, with their next card moving to the top of the pile.

As a demo each card is given the same dimensions but this can be changed as the visibility of each card is set to hidden when it is not being seen. Note, display none is not used as this stops the element being rendered at all so the transitions don't work properly. By contrast visibility keeps the space for the element, it just isn't visible.

```css
#slider label {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -1px #000;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: right 0.6s ease;
}

#slider input:nth-of-type(1):checked~label:nth-of-type(1),
#slider input:nth-of-type(1):checked~label:nth-of-type(2),
#slider input:nth-of-type(2):checked~label:nth-of-type(2),
#slider input:nth-of-type(2):checked~label:nth-of-type(3),
#slider input:nth-of-type(3):checked~label:nth-of-type(3),
#slider input:nth-of-type(3):checked~label:nth-of-type(4),
#slider input:nth-of-type(4):checked~label:nth-of-type(4),
#slider input:nth-of-type(4):checked~label:nth-of-type(1) {
  visibility: visible;
}

#slider input:nth-of-type(1):checked~label:nth-of-type(1),
#slider input:nth-of-type(2):checked~label:nth-of-type(2),
#slider input:nth-of-type(3):checked~label:nth-of-type(3),
#slider input:nth-of-type(4):checked~label:nth-of-type(4) {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">

  <label for="s1" id="slide1">London</label>
  <label for="s2" id="slide2">Manchester</label>
  <label for="s3" id="slide3">Edinburgh</label>
  <label for="s4" id="slide4">Leeds</label>
</section>
```

Obviously you will want to change the dimensions and the amount of movement to suit your full use case.